# Thread commands not working in WInDbg

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-xp, windbg, process-explorer

Trying to execute thread based command in WinDbg. Setup is VMWare having XP, host is Win 7.  Based on [this](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#12_thread), trying to debug application-hang. But can not get any information out of it. For simple tilda(~) it is giving syntax error. Do I need to do some different setup in order to execute these commands? Are these "special" by any means? Because I can work with other commands.

Basically I would like WinDbg to let me monitor the status of the threads? e.g. waiting for response, sending request, or something like this.

Comment: The ~ gives a list of threads in the attached process, and has always worked for me when doing user mode debugging. please show us a sample when you get the syntax error.

Comment: If ~ gives a syntax error, we need more information. Are you running WinDbg on your host or on the guest? Do you do kernel debugging or did you attach to a process? Which version of WinDbg?

Comment: Doing Kernel Debugging, host Win 7 has WinDbg Version 6.1. kd> ~
    ^ Syntax error in '~' is what I get.

Answer (score 4):

~ change thread context only for usermode debugging.
for krnel mkode debugging see help for:
.thread
.process
!thread
!process